# Display 'M/d/yy, h:mm a' (6/15/15, 9:03 AM) datetime format in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

tried This not working =FORMAT(Fields!Parameter.Value, "M/d/yy, h:mm a") --> This is giving error

=FormatDateTime(Fields!Parameter.Value, DateFormat.ShortDate) & " "
& Hour(Fields!Parameter.Value) & ":" & Minute(Fields!Parameter.Value) ---> Here I am not able to Pull ot AM/PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set format in property window.

[image: Date Format]

Sample Format - `M/d/yyyy h:m tt`